# How can I get a specific child value from firebase depends on the date(DAY)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my data structure

[image]

So the 0 is the 1st day of the month and so on. So basically it's looping but I have no idea what should I do. I need an idea where to start or what should I do.

What I want my output is

So if its the first day of the month so thats 0 on the child the price will be 1 and the next day will be 2

This is my code

```
    mRef3 = mRef.child(key).child("promos").child("regular").child(ym).child("price").child("guest1/0");




 mRef3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String price = dataSnapshot.getKey()+": "+dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    holder.rPrice.setText("FROM " + getString(R.string.currency) + " " + price + " per night ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

CURRENT OUTPUT: 
FROM USD 0:1 per night

Comment: Please add your database structure and the expected result.

Comment: @AlexMamo Edited what i want to be my output

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo edited with my data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the value from the database for a specific day, you can do something like this:

```
DatabaseReference dayRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("price/guest1/0");
dayRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey()+": "+dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

---

If you want to read the values for all days from the database, you'll attach the listener one level higher and loop over the children of the snapshot:

```
DatabaseReference dayRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("price/guest1");
dayRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot daySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(daySnapshot.getKey()+": "+daySnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

---

If you want to get the 0-based day of the month:

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Comment: getReference("price/guest1/0"); why do i need to put the 0 to the reference?

Comment: If you want to load the value for all days, use the second snippet. If you want to load the value for a specific day, you need to know exactly what day to load the value for.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                String day1 = date.format(c);

Comment: So is your question simply: [how to determine the current (0-based) day of the month in Android?](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+how+to+determine+the+0-based+day+of+the+month) In that case it has nothing to do with Firebase, and all signs point to `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`.

Comment: I tried that and here is my query : child("price").child("guest1/" + day1);

Comment: Please update your question with the [minimal code that reproduces what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as right now it is unclear what the actual problem is. Read the link carefully please, as an MCVE is by far the most effective way to ask for help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I edited my question and put my code but your answer is correct my problem now is how can i equal the date of today to the child from firebase since it starts with 0

Comment: Thanks for your help frank i kinda getting it now

Comment: I would love to but I can't. I need 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i have understood your question cleary but if you are trying to find out the price of the particular day (i.e 1st of month is 0 then the price should give 1 and so on) then you might have to do something like this

In the methode getDay you can pass what day is it today

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("price").child("guest1").child(getDay()).addChildEventListener(
            new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,
                        @Nullable String s) {
                    //get your price here
                    String price = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,
                        @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,
                        @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: What if the day is an array so its always -1?